# Custom events not showing up in event log

Tags: c#, event-log, custom-eventlog

I'm trying to write to the application event log.  The following code executes without error under Windows 8 (when run with admin privileges), but I don't see any events showing up when looking at the Application log in the Windows Event Viewer.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Do I need to add something to app.config?

```
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace tracetest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists("TestSource"))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("TestSource", "Application");
            }
            EventLog appLog = new EventLog("Application", ".", "TestSource");
            appLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            appLog.EndInit();
            Debug.WriteLine(appLog.Entries.Count);
            appLog.WriteEntry("An entry to the Application event log.");
            Debug.WriteLine(appLog.Entries.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the TestSource event source get created?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Microsoft website, we have the following information:

> Note:
>   If a source has already been mapped to a log and you remap it to a new log, you must restart the computer for the changes to take effect.

The machine must be restarted every time you create a new custom event key. (Or just restart the EventViewer service) :)

Comment: The service you're referring has display name "Windows Event Log", and Service name "EventLog".